# Compiler error C2850 relevant to precompiled headers.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How do I fix compiler error C2850 in VS2010 C++ Express?

I am using VS2010 C++ Express to build Win32 apps on a 64-bit PC runnin 64-bit Win 7. 
I have successfully developed a number of projects.
I have been working on my current project for about 3 weeks and have successfully built Debug and Release versions of the app (i.e., they run more or less as desired.)

In an attempt to mitigate an apparent memory leakage problem, I modified a couple of functions I wrote which reference windows function DrawText().  I've successfully use DrawText(), and mbstowcs() elsewhere in this project, so I was surprised when my attempt to compile ALL source modules my project threw the following error:

error C2850: 'PCH header file' : only allowed at file scope; may not be in a nested construct

I consulted a number of C++ user websites for a solution and came up empty.

Thus far I have tried the following erstwhile remedies singularly and in combination:

(1)  Tried all 3 settings of 
        Project
        ->Properties
          ->Configuration Properties
            ->C/C++
              Precompiled Headers
                ->Precompiled Header

(2)  Eliminated stdafx.cpp from Source Files list.

(3)  Deleted   "#pragma once"   from all include files except stdafx.h.

(4)  Verified in all my code that the statements
         #pragma once 
     and
         #include "stdafx.h" 
     appear only once and in global space at the top of each file that contains    either statement.

It was suggested on one website that I start over with an empty project, but I haven't tried that yet.

Needless to say, I never had to mess with any of this nonsense before VS2010 decided to invent this latest obstacle to my productivity.

Does anyone have any insight as to how to resolve this problem?

Comment: If stdafx.h is your precompiled header, this is saying you are only allowed to #include it in .cpp files and not other .h files.

Comment: Problem was due to the accidental deletion of a DeleteObject() statement, since remedied.  The memory leakage problem is solved.  Sorry for the false alarm.  Solving this problem somehow also eliminated the C2850 error.  This thread can be closed.